# Fragment occupies more space than it's content would need

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

When I declare a `PreferenceFragment` in my layout file like this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/webViewLayout"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/toggleView"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:name="path_to_fragment.ToggleView_PrefFragment" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[only the `PreferenceFragment` appears on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaO5B.png) and the WebView's height is equal to zero (because all the space is being occupied by the fragment).

But why is that? I'm declaring the fragment's height as "wrap_content", so it should only take up the space it needs to...

Any help is appreciated :)

**EDIT:**

ToggleView_PrefFragment:

```
package fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

import R;

public final class ToggleView_PrefFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.toggle_view);

    }
}
```

toggle_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:summary="Summary"
        android:title="Title"
    />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: The fragment's view, doesn't have the height set to ```match_parent```  ?

Comment: It shouldn't be set to match_parent. My problem is that it behaves like it would be set to match_parent.

Comment: I suggested to check if the Fragment's view (I assume you create a fragment that has a xml file for layout) doesn't have the height set to ```match_parent``` if it is set to ```match_parent``` then it's expected behaviour.

Comment: Now I understand, sorry. I think my problem is that the PreferenceScreen (I'm appending the files to the thread) automatically preserves all available space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `WebView` can't be visible, because your root layout is **horizontal** `LinearLayout`.
Your `PreferenceFragment` has `match_parent` width, so there is no space for `WebView`.
Additionally you made your `WebView` to match all available space using weight.

I assume you want to have `PreferenceFragment` on top with `wrap_content` height. And below `PreferenceFragment` have `WebView` that matches all the rest vertical space.

In this case you should do something like:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/webViewLayout"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/toggleView"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:name="path_to_fragment.ToggleView_PrefFragment" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Change `LinearLayout` orientation to **vertical**.
For your WebView switch width and height options. And change width to match_parent.

Hope it helps

Comment: You sir, are a god! Thank you very much :)